# Could not find module "...Python38\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\lib_lightgbm.dll"

Tags: python, lightgbm

I'm trying to install LightGBM GPU build for Python. I installed from Git and have successfully built LightGBM, the test run turned out as expected.

```
[LightGBM] [Info] Iteration:100, training auc : 0.997687
[LightGBM] [Info] Iteration:100, valid_1 binary_logloss : 0.519711
[LightGBM] [Info] Iteration:100, valid_1 auc : 0.81798
[LightGBM] [Info] 14.887669 seconds elapsed, finished iteration 100
[LightGBM] [Info] Finished training
```

However, when I tried to

```
import LightGBM as gbm
```

Python returned

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\lib_lightgbm.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I have tried run `setup.py install --precompile`, but it did not help. Have I missed something in the process?

Comment: do you have more than one Python interpreter installed?

Comment: Beside 3.8, I have a default Python 2.7 came with WSL2. I have make sure to use Python 3.8 when run `setup.py`. The `lib_lightgbm.dll` is clearly in the path, but somehow Python not recognize it, may be it's a PATH issue but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Python 3.8 the .dll search method has changed. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) for reference. Try `os.chdir('path_to_working_dlls_directoy')` or if that does not work try `os.add_dll_directory("path_to_working_dlls_directoy")`

Comment: Thx, I have tried and it seemed not working. Don't know why but I'll keep digging.

Comment: did you use the path to the python interpreter that has that library installed? since you have two interpreters you could have it installed on one and you used the path to the wrong one?

Comment: Thx for your effort. I have deleted the build, reinstall CMake, restart the PC, and somehow it worked. I still don't know why.

Comment: well hey i guess sometimes it is that simple.